# Safari Issue: Intermittent Issues with window.postMessage in React When Communicating with an Iframe

Tags: reactjs, safari

I am encountering an intermittent issue in a React application where the handleMessage function is not being triggered as expected when using window.postMessage for communication with an iframe. This problem occurs inconsistently: it works correctly about 5% of the time, but fails to trigger the handleMessage function the rest of the time.

The setup involves a Wix website where I'm posting a URL directly to an iframe. Here is the relevant code snippet from the Wix site.

```
window.onmessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data) {
    let receivedData = event.data;
    var iframe = document.getElementById('embedId');
    var targetOrigin = 'https://www.example.com';
    var message = {
      'type': 'urlRequest',
      'url': receivedData.data.url,
      'userParams': receivedData.data.userParams
    }
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin);
  }
};
```

In the React application, the iframe is supposed to receive the message and handle it. Here's the code from the React side:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleMessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data.type && event.data.type === 'urlRequest') {
      const params = queryString.parseUrl(event.data.url).query;
      const attributes = {
        userId: params.userId,
      };
      setAttributes(attributes);
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);
  };
}, []);
```

The issue seem to be browser-specific, as it works perfectly in Chrome and Mozilla. However, I'm unable to determine why handleMessage is not consistently called. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can offer insights into what might be going wrong?